# I cant insert data to my database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created class called SQliteAdapter and here is the code

```
package com.project.ElectronicBloodBank;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SQliteAdapter {

SQliteHelper helper;
public SQliteAdapter(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    helper=new SQliteHelper(context);
}
public long inertData(String name, String age, String address, String phone, String bloodtype)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(SQliteHelper.NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(SQliteHelper.AGE, age);
    contentValues.put(SQliteHelper.ADDRESS, address);
    contentValues.put(SQliteHelper.PHONE, phone);
    contentValues.put(SQliteHelper.BLOODTYPE, bloodtype);
    long id=db.insert(SQliteHelper.NAME, null, contentValues);
    return id;
}

static class SQliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="Ebbdb";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="Donor";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    private static final String UID="_id";
    private static final String NAME="Name";
    private static final String AGE="Age";
    private static final String ADDRESS="Address";
    private static final String PHONE="Phone";
    private static final String BLOODTYPE="Bloodtype";
    private static final String CREAT_TABLE="CREATE TABLE"+TABLE_NAME+"("+UID+" integer PRIMARY KEY     autoincrement, "+NAME+" VARCHAR(200), "+AGE+" TEXT, "+ADDRESS+" TEXT, "+PHONE+" TEXT, "+BLOODTYPE+"     TEXT);";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME;
    private Context context;
     public SQliteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
        Message.message(context, "constructor called");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREAT_TABLE);
            Message.message(context, "onCreate called");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Message.message(context, ""+e);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Message.message(context, "onUpgrade called");
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Message.message(context, ""+e);
        }

    }

}
}
```

and I also created a insert this code to my ActivityTwo

```
package com.project.ElectronicBloodBank;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ActivityTwo extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText etname, etage, etaddress, etphone, etbloodtype;
SQliteAdapter SQliteHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

    etname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname);
    etage=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etage);
    etaddress=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaddress);
    etphone=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etphone);
    etbloodtype=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etbloodtype);
    SQliteHelper=new SQliteAdapter(this);
}

public void btnsave(View view)
{
    String nam=etname.getText().toString();
    String age=etage.getText().toString();
    String addrs=etaddress.getText().toString();
    String phn=etphone.getText().toString();
    String btyp=etbloodtype.getText().toString();

    long id=SQliteHelper.inertData(nam, age, addrs, phn, btyp);
    if(id<0)
    {
        Message.message(this, "Unsuccessful");
    }
    else
    {
        Message.message(this, "Successfuly Inserted Donor");

        }
    }
}
```

The problems are :
The database was created but there's no table!!!
I fill the information it show this in logcat

```
11-05 01:00:55.927: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(650): sqlite returned: error
code = 1, msg = no such table: Name,
db=/data/data/com.project.ElectronicBloodBank/databases/Ebbdb
```

and bellow

```
11-05 01:00:55.947: E/SQLiteDatabase(650): Error inserting Name=omar
Bloodtype=+AB Phone=733310906 Age=23 Address=Sana'a
```

So where is the main problem.?

Answer (score 2):

First thing, try changing this line:

```
long id=db.insert(SQliteHelper.NAME, null, contentValues);
```

with:

```
long id=db.insert(SQliteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
```

Comment: are you still getting the same error, message?, please post it here

Comment: 11-07 01:00:55.927:I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(650): sqlite returned: error
    code = 1, msg = no such table: Name,
    db=/data/data/com.project.ElectronicBloodBank/databases/Ebbdb
    11-07 01:00:55.947: E/SQLiteDatabase(650): Error inserting     Name=omar
    Bloodtype=+AB Phone=733310906 Age=23 Address=Sana'a

Comment: that's weird, this seems the same error, even though the table name should be "Donor", but the error says "Name"

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues, although the main one is the one pointed out by jucas.

- For everyupdate (onUpgrade call) you are using, you are always deleting the complete database and creating a new database. This could be dangerous. I recommend you to create some protection here and have some tracking of the database version.
- I can see that you call your instance of SQliteAdapter as SQliteHelper. I think this is very dangerous. Try to create a simple name that is not another type, for example, mSqadapter. I am not so expert to say if this could be a source of error, but sounds odd to me.
- Applying the suggestion from jucas (replacing SQliteHelper.NAME by SQliteHelper.TABLE_NAME) should provide you a different error. Could you show the new error in your report? That could help looking for the error.

Anycase, I suggest also to try the second suggestion I included.

Hope it helps.